# server DNS address could not be found error after change nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, dns-zone

i changed my website's nameservers yesterday ( from godaddy to clouflare.com). But my website shows "an server DNS address could not be found" error today. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: There is not enough details. What your change?

Comment: nameservers. I have changed the nameservers to cloudflare.com.

Comment: `But my website shows "an server DNS address could not be found" error today` - I don't understand that statement. Do you mean that your web browser shows that when you try to go to your website?

Comment: Did you set copy your DNS records to Cloudflare?

Comment: Did you ask Cloudflare for help? You are using their services so why not ask them?